# How to use Tkinter Scrollbar inside canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

We are trying to design a form using tkinter.we stuck at a point we are not able to link scrollbar in the form.

```
def init_Widget(self):
    #Second Info Frame
    self.CanvasFrame =Canvas(self, height=200,width=550,bg="red")
    self.scrollbar=Scrollbar(self.CanvasFrame)[enter image description here][1]
    self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    self.CanvasFrame.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.OrderFrame = LabelFrame(self.CanvasFrame,text="Billing Info",padx=5,pady=5 ,highlightthickness=2 )
    self.Header1lbl = Label(self.OrderFrame,text="Item", foreground="white",font=("Courier", 10,"bold") , bg="#008080",relief="raised", borderwidth = 2, width=40,padx=1,pady=1)
    self.Header1lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.Header2lbl = Label(self.OrderFrame,text="Qty", foreground="white",font=("Courier", 10,"bold") , bg="#008080",relief="raised", borderwidth = 2,width= 10,padx=1,pady=1)
    self.Header2lbl.grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.Header3lbl = Label(self.OrderFrame,text="Rate", foreground="white",font=("Courier", 10,"bold") , bg="#008080",relief="raised", borderwidth = 2,width= 10,padx=1,pady=1)
    self.Header3lbl.grid(row=0,column=2)
    for i in range(1,8):
        self.ItemInput1 = Entry(self.OrderFrame,width=54)
        self.ItemInput1.grid(row=i,column=0)
        self.Qty1 = Entry(self.OrderFrame,width=14)
        self.Qty1.grid(row=i,column=1)
        self.Rate1 = Entry(self.OrderFrame,width=14)
        self.Rate1.grid(row=i,column=2) 
    self.CanvasFrame.configure(scrollregion=self.CanvasFrame.bbox("all"))
    self.OrderFrame.pack(padx=3,pady=3)
    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.CanvasFrame.yview)
    self.CanvasFrame.pack()
    self.CanvasFrame.pack_propagate(False)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should not put `self.scrollbar` inside `self.CanvasFrame`, put it in `self` instead.

```
self.scrollbar=Scrollbar(self)
```

Second you should not use `pack()` to put `self.OrderFrame` into `self.CanvasFrame`, use `self.CanvasFrame.create_window()` instead.

Finally you should update `scrollregion` after inserting all the widgets into `self.OrderFrame` and `self.OrderFrame` is added into `self.CanvasFrame`.

```
    #self.OrderFrame.pack(padx=3,pady=3)
    self.CanvasFrame.create_window(0, 0, window=self.OrderFrame, anchor='nw')
    self.CanvasFrame.update()
    self.CanvasFrame.configure(scrollregion=self.CanvasFrame.bbox("all"))
```

---

*UPDATE:* You can use a frame to hold the canvas and the scrollbar:

```
def init_Widget(self):
    # frame for the canvas and scrollbar
    self.ScrollFrame = Frame(self)
    self.ScrollFrame.pack()

    self.CanvasFrame = Canvas(self.ScrollFrame, height=200,width=550,bg="red")
    self.CanvasFrame.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)

    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.ScrollFrame,command=self.CanvasFrame.yview)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

    self.CanvasFrame.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

    self.OrderFrame=LabelFrame(self.CanvasFrame,text="Billing Info",padx=5,pady=5 ,highlightthickness=2 )
    self.CanvasFrame.create_window(0, 0, window=self.OrderFrame, anchor='nw')

    self.Header1lbl = Label(self.OrderFrame,text="Item", foreground="white",font=("Courier", 10,"bold") , bg="#008080",relief="raised", borderwidth = 2, width=40,padx=1,pady=1)
    self.Header1lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.Header2lbl = Label(self.OrderFrame,text="Qty", foreground="white",font=("Courier", 10,"bold") , bg="#008080",relief="raised", borderwidth = 2,width= 10,padx=1,pady=1)
    self.Header2lbl.grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.Header3lbl = Label(self.OrderFrame,text="Rate", foreground="white",font=("Courier", 10,"bold") , bg="#008080",relief="raised", borderwidth = 2,width= 10,padx=1,pady=1)
    self.Header3lbl.grid(row=0,column=2)

    for i in range(1,18):
        self.ItemInput1 = Entry(self.OrderFrame,width=54)
        self.ItemInput1.grid(row=i,column=0)
        self.Qty1 = Entry(self.OrderFrame,width=14)
        self.Qty1.grid(row=i,column=1)
        self.Rate1 = Entry(self.OrderFrame,width=14)
        self.Rate1.grid(row=i,column=2) 

    self.CanvasFrame.update()
    self.CanvasFrame.configure(scrollregion=self.CanvasFrame.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: Hi acwi668 .we tried option that you mention above but it is not working for us .could you please help us  to add scrollbar to adjacent to orderframe as that thing should be scroll-able. for your refrence we have post the complete code

Comment: Then use a frame to hold the canvas and the scrollbar.